# Accessing my cookies set on my domain when being called from another domain?

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, subdomain

Would like to know now if this should be possible. A user visits my Site www.example.com and I set a cookie on *.example.com. Later that user vists another site that is not a sub domain of mine (a.com). On a.com they have a script that calls out to www.example.com say to hit an api. Will that request include any and all cookies that may have been set on my domain for me to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this out myself with a test server and the browser will send all cookies that match you domain with any request to your domain regardless of the source location

Comment: The request will contain your cookies (example.com) but this is because the browser is being redirected to your domain. It does not mean that the other domain (a.com) can access your cookies.